# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos^{2}(x)-1+y^{2}}{\arctan^{4}(x)+y^{2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, multivariate-polynomial

Evaluate a the following limit in two variables:

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)\ }\ \frac{\cos^{2}(x)-1+y^{2}}{\ \ \arctan^{4}(x)+y^{2}}$$
>   or prove it doesn't exist.

---

I tried to simplify the expression, by replacing: $\cos^{2}(x) -1= \sin^{2}(x)$. After that I was stuck.

Also, I know it's possible to find some limit under the assumption that the limit **exists**. But if I'm no allowed to make such assumption,  is it allowed to calculate the limit by fixing the value of $x$ and then fixing the value of $y$?

I can't find a way to prove that this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Evaluate the limit along the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:

- For $x=0,$ $$\frac{\cos^{2}(0)-1+y^{2}}{\arctan^{4}(0)+y^{2}}=\frac{y^2}{y^2}=1$$
- For $y=0,$ $$\frac{\cos^{2}(x)-1+0^{2}}{\arctan^{4}(x)+0^{2}}=\frac{\cos^{2}(x)-1}{x^2}\frac{x^4}{\arctan^{4}(x)}\frac1{x^2}\to \infty$$